# Equations in Two Columns Format

Tags: equations

I would like to create these two equations in the overleaf with TeX Live 2022 in two column template.

Here is the expectation (yellow highlighted):

[image: ![expectation]

Zoom in version:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then, this is the code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:corollary_i}
    \max_{i^{\ast} =1,...,n} (q_i^{\ast}\cdot p_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})c_i^{\ast} \quad  \forall i^{\ast}\geq(n-1), q_i^{\ast}\cdot c_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})p_i^{\ast} \quad   \text{for $i^{\ast} = n$}) \geq (n-1)w + nv
    \end{equation}
 
    \item
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:corollary_ii}
    \max_{i^{\ast\ast} =1,...,n} (q_i^{\ast\ast}\cdot p_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})c_i^{\ast\ast} \quad  \forall i^{\ast\ast}\geq(n-1), q_i^{\ast\ast}\cdot c_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})p_i^{\ast\ast} \quad  \text{for $i^{\ast} = n$} \geq (n+1)w + (n+2)v
    \end{equation}    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However, the printed result is as follows (the equations surpass the column space).

[image: result]

Does anyone how to ensure those two equations will fit into 1 column?
Thank you.

Comment: Your equations are very long (apparently) and has unclear structure. Please, provide a sketch, how should they like to be..

Comment: Equations have to be manually broken/formatted to fit the columns.  I would lose the enumerate, as it will only reduce the available width.  Or at least use enumitem to get rid of the hanging indentation.

Comment: Hi @Zarko and John, I edited the expected equations in the questions page. Can you take a look, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your MWE is not close to what you show to like have
- equation also on image is quite long
- a possible way is to reduce font size in equation and left out not needed sympo `\cdot and parenthesis
- for equation  I suggest to use `cases` from `mathtools`

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
    \begin{flalign}
(i) &   \max_{i^{\ast} = 1,\dotsc,n} 
        \begin{cases}
        q_i^{\ast} p_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})c_i^{\ast} & i^{\ast}\leq(n-1)    \\
        q_i^{\ast} p_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})p_i^{\ast} & i^{\ast}=n
        \end{cases}      
        \geq W_1(n)    \label{eq:corollary_i} \\
(ii) & \max_{i^{\ast\ast}=1,...,n}
        \begin{cases}
            q_i^{\ast\ast}p_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})c_i^{\ast\ast} 
                & i^{\ast\ast}\leq(n-1) \\ 
            q_i^{\ast\ast} c_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})p_i^{\ast\ast}
                & i^{\ast} = n        
        \end{cases}
         \geq W_2(n)      \label{eq:corollary_ii} 
    \end{flalign}
}%
where $W_1(n) = (n+1)w + nv$ and $W_2(n) = (n-1)w + (n+2)v$.

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
With `enumerate` list and `nccmath` package for shifting equation to the left and `multlined` to split longer equation into two lines. This enable to write equation without reducing of font inside them:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{nccmath,  mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{fleqn}[0pt]
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),wide]
\item 
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:corollary_i}
\max_{i^{\ast} = 1,\dotsc,n}
        \begin{cases}
        q_i^{\ast} p_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})c_i^{\ast} & i^{\ast}\leq(n-1)    \\
        q_i^{\ast} p_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})p_i^{\ast} & i^{\ast}=n
        \end{cases}
        \quad   \geq W_1(n)
    \end{equation}
\item 
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:corollary_ii}
\max_{i^{\ast\ast}=1,...,n}
        \begin{cases}
            \begin{multlined}
                q_i^{\ast\ast}p_i^{\ast\ast} + \\[-2ex]
                    (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})c_i^{\ast\ast}
            \end{multlined}
                &   i^{\ast\ast}\leq(n-1) \\[3ex]
           \begin{multlined}
            q_i^{\ast\ast} c_i^{\ast\ast} + \\[-2ex]
                    (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})p_i^{\ast\ast}
             \end{multlined}
               &    i^{\ast} = n
        \end{cases}
        \quad   \geq W_2(n)
    \end{equation}
\end{enumerate}
\end{fleqn}
where $W_1(n) = (n+1)w + nv$ and $W_2(n) = (n-1)w + (n+2)v$.

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this works for you?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{strip}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:corollary_i}
    \max_{i^{\ast} =1,\ldots,n} (q_i^{\ast}\cdot p_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})c_i^{\ast} \quad  \forall i^{\ast}\geq(n-1), q_i^{\ast}\cdot c_i^{\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast})p_i^{\ast} \quad   \text{for $i^{\ast} = n$}) \geq (n-1)w + nv
    \end{equation}
 
    \item
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:corollary_ii}
    \max_{i^{\ast\ast} =1,\ldots,n} (q_i^{\ast\ast}\cdot p_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})c_i^{\ast\ast} \quad  \forall i^{\ast\ast}\geq(n-1), q_i^{\ast\ast}\cdot c_i^{\ast\ast} + (1-q_i^{\ast\ast})p_i^{\ast\ast} \quad  \text{for $i^{\ast} = n$} \geq (n+1)w + (n+2)v
    \end{equation}    
\end{enumerate}
\end{strip}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align*` or `multiline`

Comment: Can you please show some code, that shows, how this can be used to solve the issue? Best would be, to add a working example, that can be copied and tried out. Currently this answer is more or less just a comment not a complete answer.